# How to get an empty line in text file in c?

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a file which contains some data regarding anomalies. Each byte of data is written in a new line in a text file. Now to separate the data of different anomalies, I have added an empty line i.e. "\n" after the last byte of each data set. I am using the function:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
     data[counter++] = (unsigned char)strtol(line,NULL,16);
     printf("The data received is %08x\n\r", data[counter - 1]);
}
```

So how do I detect if the line is the empty line?

Comment: Can you post more code ? May be the full function.

Comment: `if (*line == '\n')` ... the line is empty...  (**note:** if the last line in the file has a non-POSIX ending (e.g. no `'\n'`), you need a separate check for the last line)

Comment: Am I to use single colons around \n or double colons?

Comment: How many characters are there on an empty line, when you remember that the line includes a newline?  How many characters are there on a non-empty line when you remember that a non-empty line includes more characters than just the newline?  That's how you do it!  (Or you can look at the first character in the line data, but you know how many characters are there because you saved it assigning to `read`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, all *line-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgets` and POSIX `getline`) read up to, and include, the `'\n'` in the buffers they fill, `line` in your case. So to check if you have encountered (or read) an empty-line, you simply need to check if the contents of `line` is `'\n'`. To get the first character in `line` all you need do is dereference it, e.g. `*line` and compare the first character against the `'\n'` character, e.g.

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    if (*line == '\n') {
        /* handle empty line */
    }
    data[counter++] = (unsigned char)strtol(line,NULL,16);
    printf("The data received is %08x\n\r", data[counter - 1]);
}
```

**note** dereferening `line` with `*line` is the same as `line[0]`. You are just checking the first character. This is due to the pointer equivalent of an index. For example `line[x]` in pointer notation is `*(line + x)`. (when `x=0`, it's just `*line`)

Also note, you should validate the `strtol` conversion by including `errno.h` and checking `errno` after every conversion. You should also save the result of `strtol` in a `long` to prevent under/overflow and then compare `tmp` against `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` (found in `limits.h`) before assigning to `data[counter++]`, e.g.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
...

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    long tmp;
    if (*line == '\n') {
        /* handle empty line */
    }
    errno = 0;                      /* reset errno to 0 */
    tmp = strtol(line,NULL,16);     /* convert to a long */
    if (errno != 0) {
        /* handle error */
    }
    if (0 <= tmp && tmp <= UCHAR_MAX) {  /* check it will fit in unsigned char */
        data[counter++] = (unsigned char)tmp;
        printf("The data received is %08x\n\r", data[counter - 1]);
    }
    else
        /* handle error - tmp too large for unsigned char */
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: What about the colons? Is it the same if I use double colons?

Comment: **colons?**, are you talking about the `*` dereference operator?

Comment: Are (*line == '\n') and (*line == "\n") the same?

Comment: **NO!!**, double-quotes `"..."` create a **string literal**, single-quotes indicate a **character**. So `"\n"` creates the *string literal* `{'\n', 0}` while `'\n'` is the *character* `newline`. Since you declare `char *line;`, when you dereference a `char *` (with e.g. `*line`), you get a `char`, so use the **character** comparison (single-quotes).